# Xsocket doesn't work , If router or ISP is preventing ICMP Traffic

Tags: c#, xsockets.net

I am using Xsocket for Duplex communication between server -client .

Every thing was working fine . my sample can work on different network but i find out the Main issue in Xsocket..

if Client is behind Router , proxy and Fire Wall  preventing ICMP traffic Then client Can Not Initiate Connection with Server.

mean those client who can't ping Google . yahoo etc but can access them . those can't initiate connection with server.

Should i've to enable ICMP protocol on client fire Wall ?

I don't know how to handle this issue in my Program .

Can you Help me please ??

Thanks Advance .

Comment: Please don't Randomly Capitalize words, that's not how English works. If your question is _"When a firewall blocks my traffic, should I let it allow that traffic to let my program function?"_ , the answer is _"yes"_.

Comment: I'm sorry . well if firewall blocking ICMP protocol then xsocket client  not get response from server.. how to handle this issue?

Comment: By allowing ICMP traffic or choosing another protocol.

Comment: Xsocket is using TCP/IP . 
I don't want to allow ICMP traffic on Client Machine.Can you tell me using xsocket how can i handle this issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SignalR or maybe SocketIO and see how they do ?

I talked to the best guy I know in networking and he said that

You should not disable ICMP totally, but instead be very careful if changing ICMP at all.
Use WSS (ssl/tls), since routers will let that traffic through
Out of scope, but  turning ICMP off = "fake security" maybe solve your issue .

Comment: Thanks you .its help me .its mean i need setting on firewall .